# SP 2016: Disabled Sandboxed Code Service restarts itself

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, central-administration, performance

In an effort to stop the `spucworkerprocessproxy` process, I shutdown the Sandboxed Code Service (because we use no sandboxed code) by running:

```
$serviceInstance =  Get-SPServiceInstance | ? { $_.TypeName -eq '
Microsoft Sharepoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service';

Stop-SPServiceInstance -Identity $serviceInstance.Id -Confirm:$false;
```

After running the above, the status of the Sandboxed Code Service changed to "Unprovisioning" and the `spucworkerprocessproxy` was shutdown and all of its attendant database load vanished. And there was much rejoicing.

However, the following morning, the service was back up and running, along with `spucworkerprocessproxy`. Sad trombone.

How can we shut this thing down, and **keep** it off? Thanks.

Comment: what is minrole is for the servers? front-end role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the use of a MinRole other than Custom. As outlined in [MinRole and associated services for each server role](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/administration/description-of-minrole-and-associated-services-in-sharepoint-server-2016#minrole-and-associated-services-for-each-server-role), any associated service will auto-start for that role (the exception being if there is no Service Application, where applicable, which it isn't for Sandbox).

If you switch to the Custom role, while you do lose benefits of using MinRole, you can stop the Sandbox Code service as you see fit.